# How to get GPS location in Ubuntu Touch installed on Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, gps

I want to write a python program that reads current location of the device.

To make it I'm looking for an API to access current GPS location in Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7.

This seems like a basic functionality but after searching for an answer for two days and checking countless methods I don't have working solution. There is test_gps program in libhybris that reads location somehow, also webbrowser have somehow access to the location (but I don't know how). I thought there is dbus interface for reading location, but I found none.

It would be best to have easy API but if there is none - any working solution to read location at given moment will be good.

Comment: Lack of support in Ubuntu Touch is painfully too obvious...